# How do I create a jquery function with callbacks

Tags: jquery, function, plugins

How do I create a plugin / jquery function with the use of the following

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  $.confirm({
     yes : function(){
        // some code
     },
     no : function(){
        // Some code
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you expecting to use the `prompt()` function?  Or how are you expecting to display the prompt?  And, is there not a message that goes in the prompt?

Comment: Suggest you get the code working without a plugin and then try to integrate it into a plugin. You gave no explanation of what it is supposed to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, define the plugin

```
$.confirm = function(params) {
    if (confirm(params.message))
        params.yes();
    else
        params.no();

    return this; //to allow chaining
}
```

Now you can use this plugin as

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $.confirm({
        message: "Are you sure?",
        yes: function(){},
        no: function(){}
    });
});
```

Comment: mixing `$.fn.plugin` and `$.plugin`. Shouldn't be in `$.fn` unless used with selector

Comment: @charlietfl, are you saying that the question wants me to wrap the click in the plugin as well?

Comment: no am saying that `$.confirm` is undefined when you declare it as `$.fn.confirm`.   Would need to be called as `$().confirm` if use `$.fn`

Comment: example  http://jsfiddle.net/bthm0cyf/1

Comment: Got it! is this better?

Comment: Please change vote on the answer up if you think it works, thanks!

Comment: that wasn't me but will upvote anyway

Comment: Thanks saada, works very well but there is a problem, why if the button is clicked again after the alert appears, alerts will appear two times and so on. Please help, Here my code https://jsfiddle.net/rahmat/orqregtr/

Comment: @user3056814, you were binding the click event multiple times. Here's my update https://jsfiddle.net/saada/orqregtr/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Sadaa, and sorry with my English.